# gdb step into dynamic function

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, openssl, function-pointers

I'm debugging a segfault in OpenSSL's library where the function call

```
s->method->ssl_read(s,buf,num)
```

is set by a dynamic function pointer.  I want to step into it when it points to

```
ssl23_read
```

However setting a breakpoint in `ssl23_read` doesn't work.  I'm not sure how debugging works with dynamic function pointers and it's intuitive to me that the answer might be "differently" or "not."  What debugging strategies would you use in this case?

By the way just swapping the call out doesn't work, or at least not easily - the OpenSSL library has some checks in place to make sure you don't call the function directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> setting a breakpoint in ssl23_read doesn't work

Doesn't work in what way?

If GDB sets the breakpoint, but the breakpoint never fires, then either

1. The function is not actually called, or
2. There is a bug in GDB, and it sets the breakpoint incorrectly.

If it's 2, check whether the bug still exists in the most recent GDB, and file a bug report for it. As a workaround, `break * &ssl23_read` will likely set the breakpoint such that it *will* fire.

Comment: Actually, it looks like (1).  I incorrectly determined the function it was set to, just a gdb "print" command told me the right one.  My errors are stranger, it turns out.